# Unit-testing model changes in Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, modeling

I have a `ProductController` class and a `Product` model. Everytime the `Create` action in the `ProductController` is called, it creates a new `Product` based on `FormCollection` and then it calls a function inside `Product` to change a date:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
{
    Product product = new Product();
    TryUpdateModel(product, form);

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        product.ChangeDate(form["date"]);
        repository.SaveProduct(product);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
        return View();
}
```

I was wondering how I can test `Product` so I know `.ChangeDate` is being called (via Moq's `Verify`). I did not use the Asp.Net automatic model-binding because I want to catch any binding exception via `TryUpdateModel`. I am not sure if i should put `.ChangeDate` in the Controller or Repository class. I am using Moq, MVC3, and Entity Framework 4. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup an expectation on the `SaveProduct` method of the mocked repository so that it is called with a specific argument. This specific argument will be the product which is constructed inside the controller action. Then you can assert that the `Date` property of this object is the same as the one you passed as argument in the `Create` action in the form collection.

```
var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
mock.Setup(
    x => x.SaveProduct(
        It.Is<Product>(p => p.Date == someExpectedDate)
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Darin. I never thought of that! Is there a way to setup multiple expectations? So not only Date is checked? Just wondering for future reference...

Comment: @Alex, sure: `p.Date == someExpectedDate && p.Foo == "bar" && ...`